# Get one record over period with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a big query creating a history of object changes. In short it result looks like this:

```
id     changedOn      recordtype
1      2019-12-5      history
1      2020-01-1      history
1      2020-01-7      actual
2      2018-10-9      history
```

The result I want:

```
id     changedOn      recordtype
1      2019-12-5      history
1      2020-01-7      actual
2      2018-10-9      history
```

If there is 2 records in the same month on each id I want to ommit history records for this Month.

I would like to avoid `cursor` if it possible. But I'm stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one record per month with a preference for "actual", then use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id, year(changedOn), month(changedOn) order by recordtype) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you want all "actual" records for a month -- and then if there are none -- all the history records, I would recommend logic like this:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.recordtype = 'actual' or
      (t.recordtype = 'history' and
       not exists (select 1
                   from t t2
                   where t2.id = t.id and
                         t2.recordtype = 'actual' and
                         year(t2.changedon) = year(t.changedon) and
                         month(t2.changedon) = month(t.changedon) 
                   );
```

These two approaches are subtly different.  But you will only notice the differences if you have multiple "actual"s or "history"s in a single month for a single id.

Comment: Thank you. I don't know why I didn't think about `rownumber()`. I use it in subquery earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the records with changedOn that are not the most recent

```
        select * from tbl a 
    where not exists
(select 1 from tbl b where a.id = b.id and a.recordtype = b.recordtype and a.changedOn < b.changedOn )
```